# Ruby: Soap4r: How do I get the raw request sent to my soap server?

Tags: ruby, soap, soap4r

I have a connection open and am doing:

```
values = [1, 'test']
connection.return_response_as_xml = true
response = connection.send(method_name.to_sym(), *values)
```

and that works fine and all. but I want to see the raw request sent across... is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Savon (http://github.com/rubiii/savon) if possible. I know Savon will log the request and the response by default.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to write my xml requests and responses to the console.

```
service = WebServiceSoap.new
service.wiredump_dev = STDERR;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been ages since I worked with soap4r (I do all SOAP work with Savon these days), but as far as I can remember this should do the trick:

```
connection.wiredump_file_base = 'log/soap/' # or whatever directory you want log files in
```

Bear in mind that with this, the log files will be overwritten with each call.